# How do I get Poulsbo (GMA500) drivers to work?

Tags: xorg, 9.10, gma500

I'm trying to get working the Poulbo driver under Ubuntu 9.10. I've installed `poulsbo-driver-2d` `poulsbo-driver-3d` `poulsbo-config` packages from `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gma500/ppa`.

The packages installation is working. After I have to put in xorg.conf driver "psb".
Then I reboot and I have no more display. I have to switch back to vesa in order to display back.

Can someone give me some kind of solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Ubuntu [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo/) where explain well about GMA500 video hardware